# How do I get Nancy to dispose of my InRequestScope()'d objects when using Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject, nancy

I have simple application with Nancy and Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject. We have to use Ninject, because the web app is part of a larger set of applications that already use Ninject.

I tried different setups:

- Just `Nancy` and `Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject`
- With `Ninject.Web.Common`, which registers two `HttpModules` using web activator
- By overriding `GetApplicationContainer()` and returning the kernel that is created `Ninject.Web.Common`

The binding is as simple as

```
protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(IKernel kernel, NancyContext context)
{
    kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>().InRequestScope();
}
```

and is located in my custom Nancy bootstrapper. `IRepository` extends `IDisposable`, of course.

But with none of these setups was the `Dispose()` method of my `Repository` called.

What is the correct way to setup per-request bindings that call `Dispose()` after the request has been completed?

Comment: @RobSiklos Flowers are not available as NuGet package, this is not an option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. The information provided on https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject seems not to be enough. I found the following on https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Container-Support:

> The container parameter in ConfigureRequestContainer() is a child container which is disposed at the end of the request.

and

> Container here is a child container. I.e. singletons here are in request scope.

Apparently, `InSingletonScope()`is required, so that the per-request kernel disposes the object. With that solution all the Ninject.Web stuff is not even needed!